# Why are Ephraim and Menashe blessed first?

Tags: age, shevatim-12-tribes, vayechi

In Ber. 49, Yaakov blessed his 12 sons in a particular order, at least based on the various notes to the Stone edition of the chumash -- he started with the sons of Leah (in a specific order) and then went to the maid servant's children (in a particular order though not purely by age, for example in pasuk 20) and then to Rachel's sons.

Before this, he raised up Ephraim and Menashe to the status of his children (48:6). But if they were of that status, why didn't they get blessed in the order along with the other brothers? And if they were not truly of that status (at least not yet) why did they deserve to be blessed before their elders, the sons of Yaakov? Shouldn't their blessing have come either with or after the sons?

Comment: Don't those blessings seem a bit spur of the moment? Yaakov says who are these? Oh grandkids? Lemme bless them

Comment: Yaakov says that they will be Shevatim just like Reuvein and Shimon,and in gematria menashe and efraim are equal to 726 which is one more than reuven and shimon which is 725,I rem hearing a pshat that,Efraim amd Menashe were on a higher level since they grew up in the lowest place on earth in terms of Tumah and yet still they remained faithful,the Shevatim on the other hand lived in the house of Yaakov,therefore maybe they got kedima for this reason

Comment: @doubleAA,also this episode could he referring to whem Yaakov came to Egypt,and then yeats later he gave the Shevatim the brachos

Comment: @sam no it was already 17 years in

Comment: @doubleAA there are those qho hold that it isnt in chronological order

Comment: @sam Yaakov was karov lamus and then lived 17 more years?That's quite the sickness